# Why can't save some column when I use jpa and CascadeType.PERSIST

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Guys. I'm a beginer of Spring Data JPA . I found I can't save some value to table column when I use CasecadeType.PERSIST.

I have 2 simple table:

```
Parent(id int, name varchar)
Child(id int,name varchar,parent_id )
```

The domain class:

```
Parent.java

@Entity
@Table(name="Parent")
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private List<Child> children;

    // getter and setter... 
}


Child.java 

@Entity
@Table(name="Child")
public class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    // getter and setter ...
}
```

Then I execute following code using JUnit:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setName("Parent");
List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ;i ++ ) {
    children.add(new Child("Child" + (i+1)));
}
parent.setChildren(children);
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

The parent and child data is persist into database.see following :

[Parent Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy4Xk.png)

[Child Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIS58.png)

Then I execute following code:

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.findOne(18L);
parent.setName("Parent New");
List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
for(int i = 100 ; i < 106 ;i ++ ) {
    children.add(new Child("New Child" + (i+1)));
}
parent.setChildren(children);
parentRepository.save(parent);
```

I want to get the exists Parent with id(18), and add new child list in parent's children properties, but when I check database , the name column of the new inserted record in child table is null .

[Parent Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUmer.png)

[Child Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nFB.png)

Comment: i think this line parent.setChildren(children); is wrong. It should be parent.getChildren().addAll(children);

Comment: It's not worked. But when I change cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST} to cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, I got correct result. I want to know why.

Comment: i see. The thing with cascade type is that it propagates parent entity changes to children. So there are many type so PERSIST will create new children along with parent. MERGE will update changes to parent to children. since in you case you are updating parent it will work when you use MERGE type

Comment: yes that is correct, the reason you are doing merge is because .save() method will check if entity id is already present and if it is it will do .merge() implicitly, hence the cascade.persist not working

Comment: Thans Prasad Marne and Zeromus, you are right , but that is not the reason why name column of child is null .